# Is there a way to find all indexes of a certain tag in a string relatively to the same string with removed tags?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML string, with several `<em>...</em>` tags in it. I need to find all the indexes of these tags *relatively to the string, where all the tags are removed*.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


string = "<em>This</em> is <em>a sample</em> string"
string_without_tags = BeautifulSoup(string, "lxml").text

# [(0, 4), (8, 16)] <=> "This" and "a sample"
print(string_without_tags[:4], ", ", string_without_tags[8:16], sep="")
```

I think I could just use a loop, but maybe there is more efficient way to do what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.find_all(text=True)`.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

string = "<em>This</em> is <em>a sample</em> string"
soup = BeautifulSoup(string, 'html.parser')

cur, idxs = 0, []
for t in soup.find_all(text=True):
    if t.parent.name == 'em':
        idxs.append((cur, cur+len(t)))
    cur += len(t)
print(idxs)
```

Prints:

```
[(0, 4), (8, 16)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If, as your question hints at, you need the indexes only as a step towards extracting the the text from the 'em' tags, you can simply skip that step and extract the text direct.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

string = "<em>This</em> is <em>a sample</em> string"
soup = BeautifulSoup(string, 'html.parser')
print(", ".join([x.get_text() for x in soup.find_all("em")]))
```

Prints:

```
This, a sample
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Yeah, sure: if I would *just need to extract* the text inside the `<em>...</em>`, I wouldn't try to find the indexes, and do just like you did. But here I need to find out which exactly part(s) of the string has the text surrounded by the `<em>` tag, so I need to find indexes, not just the text (I gave the exctracted text in example just to make the question more clear for other people).